# ARMv7 Word Patch (CBZ)

Tags: arm

I'm disassembling an iPhone app

I'm trying to batch the instruction CBZ -> CBNZ

Instruction Code: D9 09 00 34

As per my understanding, CBZ will jump to the address if value of register is 0

I have tried to convert it to CBNZ D9 09 00 35 but that didn't help

---

D9 09 00 34

00000000: 01000100 00111001 00100000 00110000 00111001 00100000 D9 09 00000006: 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110100 00001010 00 34.

D9 09 00 35

00000000: 01000100 00111001 00100000 00110000 00111001 00100000 D9 09 00000006: 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110101 00001010 00 35

I appreciate your support

Comment: Please show us the disassembly of the relevant section, and explain what didn't work - what did you expect to see and what happens?